# Are there any free online GIS courses based around using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, references, tools, education, online

Does anyone know of any MOOCs for learning GIS which use QGIS for any practical exercises?

I've been finding QGIS a fantastic tool for work, but would like to understand it and GIS principles on a deeper level.

However, many of the online courses or MOOCs I've found when looking for something like this are based around ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are MOOCs available in varied forms I would say. Here are some resources I would point  you to.

MIT offers an open course [Introduction to GIS](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-str-001-geographic-information-system-gis-tutorial-january-iap-2016/introduction-to-gis/)

You could look into [Announcing a Certificate in Open Source Geospatial Technology](https://fossgeo.org/2016/10/04/announcing-a-certificate-in-open-source-geospatial-technology/) and [Del Mar College and the GeoAcademy program](http://www.delmar.edu/geoacademy/). Which offers courses using QGIS which you could eventually acheive a certificate.

QGIS provides a list of a number of supports that have a ton of QGIS related docuemntation/tutorials [Core contributors](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/commercial_support.html)

I like using [QGIS Tutorials and Tips](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/) for a ton of create exercises that you could work through.